# Error 1241 When Calculating Percentages

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get my percentages to equal 100%. As of right now they far surpass 100%.

I need to account for the percentages in two different tables, `ua_money_allocation` and `ua_expenses_by_school`.

I am not sure how I can add these two tables in properly without getting:

```
error code 1241, "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"
```

Query:

```
SELECT 'Salaries and Wages' as 'Category',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(Value_USD),0)) AS 'Amount',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(Value_USD)/(COUNT(DISTINCT ua_money_allocation.school_ID_FK)))) AS 'Mean',
(ROUND(SUM(ua_money_allocation.Value_USD)/
    (SUM(ua_money_allocation.Value_USD)*100,1 + 
    SUM(ua_expenses_by_school.Amount_USD)))) AS 'Percent of Total',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(Min(Value_USD),0)) AS 'Minimum',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(MAX(Value_USD),0)) AS 'Maximum'
FROM ua_money_allocation
Join ua_expenses_by_school
ON ua_money_allocation.school_ID_FK = ua_expenses_by_school.school_id_fk
WHERE ua_money_allocation.Report_yr='2015'
AND Value_USD !=0
AND Amount_USD!=0
AND Spending_Activity='Total Spent'

UNION ALL

SELECT Category,
CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(Amount_USD),0)) AS 'Amount',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(Amount_USD)/(COUNT(DISTINCT ua_expenses_by_school.school_ID_FK)))) AS 'Mean',
(ROUND(SUM(ua_expenses_by_school.Amount_USD)/
    (SUM(ua_expenses_by_school.Amount_USD)*100,1 + 
       SUM(ua_money_allocation.Value_USD)))) AS 'Percent of Total',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(Min(Amount_USD),0)) AS 'Minimum',
CONCAT('$',ROUND(MAX(Amount_USD),0)) AS 'Maximum'
FROM ua_expenses_by_school
JOIN ua_money_allocation
ON ua_expenses_by_school.school_id_fk = ua_money_allocation.school_ID_FK
WHERE ua_expenses_by_school.Report_yr='2015'
AND Amount_USD !=0
AND Value_USD !=0
AND Spending_Activity='Total Spent'
group by category
```

Answer (score 0):

Stare at this:

```
/
(   SUM(ua_expenses_by_school.Amount_USD) * 100 ,
1 + SUM(ua_money_allocation.Value_USD) )
```

Comment: How can I change the structure to make it add both?

Comment: `+` instead of `,` ???

Comment: I am using a + sign. My error is that the operand can only return 1 column

Comment: The comma says there are two columns.  You have  `/ ( this , that )`